# How to add code to new objects created by code VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create a text writing program, and when I create a new page I want to create a new sub for that text box. This is what I want to do.

```
Sub textBox1KeyDown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    makeChanged() ' makeChanged() is just a sub to change something in the tab title.
End Sub
```

Is there anyway to add that sub onto a text box made by code :

```
Dim p As New TextBox 'Is there any way to add that sub onto this?
```

Comment: Okay, now how would I add the code onto that? @Plutonix

Comment: A new tab page @Plutonix

Comment: Note that the textbox isn't declared yet so how would I do what I'm trying to do? @Plutonix

Comment: Okay, so how would I do that? @Plutonix

Comment: Are you trying to associate a custom method with each new textbox's keydown event? Are you looking for `AddHandler` ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is add a handler to the [`KeyDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx) event like this:

```
Dim p As New TextBox

AddHandler p.KeyDown, Sub(sn As Object, args As KeyEventArgs) makeChanged()
```